# Align Outlook htmlbody right to left

Tags: c#, outlook, alignment

How do I align a HTMLBody in Outlook to be right to left?

Here's my code for sending the message (the body is in a textbox)

```
       private void sendmail()
       {
       outlook.Application outApp;
       outApp = new outlook.Application();
       outlook.MailItem mail = (outlook.MailItem)(outApp.CreateItem         
       (outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem));
       mail.BodyFormat = outlook.OlBodyFormat.olFormatHTML;
       mail.To = textTo.Text;
       mail.CC = textCC.Text;
       mail.Subject = textSubject.Text;
       mail.HTMLBody = textBody.Text; 
       }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try wrapping your textBody.Text string in the following HTML

```
<table width='100%'><tr><td align="right">[YOUR TEXTBODY.TEXT VAR GOES HERE]</td></tr></table>
```

e.g.

```
mail.HTMLBody = "<table width='100%'><tr><td align="right">"+textBody.Text+"</td></tr></table>";
```

or if you wanted your body content to be a certain width

```
mail.HTMLBody = "<table width='600'><tr><td align="right">"+textBody.Text+"</td></tr></table>";
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

if by right to left align you mean RTL scripts use this

```
 mail.HTMLBody = "<p DIR=\"RTL\">" + textBody.Text + "</p>";
```

if you just want the text to be aligned either left or right use this snippet:

```
mail.HTMLBody = "<p style=\"text-align:left;\">"  + textBody.Text + "</p>";//aligned left
```